# Upside down printing

Tags: pcb, cnc

I am working on a project to print and CNC PCBs double sided simultaneously. The design for this project would require me to install my printer upside down. Can anyone think of any part of the printer that would have trouble working against gravity? Would I need special ink cartrages/Print heads? Would it even be possible?

Comment: Much better than having others speculate would be to try it. Take a ordinary printer, flip it over, and see what happens. Sounds like a complicated system asking for trouble though. Why not use one mechanism and flip the board over to do the other side?

Comment: Good point. Does not work... :( I could flip the board over, but then I lose my 1/100in accuracy. Oh well, I will figure out something else. Thank god for CAD and common sense, or I would have wasted alot of money.

Comment: Please see the comments. I will post with an edit, if I find an alternative way to "draw" upside down. I am thinking a CNC with a Sharpe for now.

Comment: Well, just turn a printer upside down and see if it still prints. That'll answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having two printers turned to a sideways orientation, such that the material moved through them vertically?  Both printers would see equivalent graviational forces in such a scenario, unlike a situation where one was upside-down, or both printers were printing onto a vertical surface which traveled sideways (which would mean that one printehead would be moving up while printing and the other would be moving down).